# Problemas para insertar valores con caracteres ç , ñ en postgres

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

Tengo un problema al cargar un archivo .CSV  con la función  `COPY`  en postgres.

La mayoría de los datos tienen caracteres `ç` o `ñ`. ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo? Intenté cambiar de UTF8 a LATIN1 y me persigue el error

> SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERROR: secuencia de bytes no válida para codificación «UTF8»: 0xf1 0x3b 0x30 0x30

Esta es una línea representativa del CSV:

```
LOCALIDAD;CENTRAL;ZONA;VIA;NUMERO;UUIIS;SALIDA LATERAL;INSTALACION;ESTADO;FECHA;
Camino De So Na Dolça; Carolina;d3333; Via 01;10;20;si;FACHADA;EN GESTION;1/5/2015;
```

```
CREATE DATABASE prueba
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'LATIN1'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'Spanish_Venezuela.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'Spanish_Venezuela.1252'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar alguna línea representativa del csv? ¿En qué instancia se dispara el error? ¿Podrías mostrar esa línea?

Comment: LOCALIDAD;CENTRAL;ZONA;VIA;NUMERO;UUIIS;SALIDA LATERAL;INSTALACION;ESTADO;FECHA;
Camino De So Na Dolça; Carolina;d3333; Via 01;10;20;si;FACHADA;EN GESTION;1/5/2015;

Comment: Que retorna el comando `\l`?

Comment: fincas2   | postgres | UTF8         | Spanish_Venezuela.1252 | Spanish_Venezuela.1252 |

Comment: Yo lo solucione utilizando en el SP que guarda los datos, puras variables NVARCHAR
si van a hacer la insercion desde C# asegurate que al enviar los parametros sea igual NVARCHAR

Comment: Usa un editor como gedit, notepad o similares, y prueba a guardar ese mismo archivo .csv con codificación UTF8, y luego asegúrate de tener la base de datos también con UTF8 con los locales correspondientes. Prueba como indica en esta web https://coderwall.com/p/a2ftvw/create-postgres-database-with-utf-8-encoding: Usa UTF8 como codificación, y los locales es_ES.utf8

Answer (score 1):

Intenta establecer el enconding antes de realizar la importaci´+del archivo csv:

```
set client_encoding to 'latin1';
```

Comment: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: la sintaxis de entrada no es v�lida para integer: �NO INFO�  ..puede ser posible que sea por la localidad del postgres ??? la mia esta LC_COLLATE = 'Spanish_Venezuela.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'Spanish_Venezuela.1252'

Comment: Me suena a que en el archivo existe un valor "NO INFO" en lugar de un dato esperado como Integer. Te recomiendo que la tabla sea de solo textos, luego trabajes con ella para transformar los tipos de datos a tus requerimientos. Puedes compartir el archivo y la instrucción COPY que estás usando?